# Mostrar textos unicode (otros idiomas) en mi tabla hecha en php usando ajax y jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hola he hecho una tabla en php en la que mostrare contenidos varios y por la que uno podrá buscar estos contenidos en la tabla. Pero me surge una cuestion cuando intento escribir letras en otros idiomas me lo muestra como `?` con interrogaciones un ejemplo creando en otro idioma un campo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de mi php mi tabla funcionara con ajax y jquery, en mi tabla en phpmyadmin se crea el valor pero si es un caracter unicode lo introduce con interrogaciones. 
La parte importante donde mostrare la tabla:

```
<div class="registros" id="agrega-registros"></div>
    <center>
        <ul class="pagination" id="pagination"></ul>
    </center>
    <!-- MODAL PARA EL REGISTRO DE PRODUCTOS-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="registra-producto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Registra o Edita un Producto</b></h4>
            </div>
            <form id="formulario" class="formulario" onsubmit="return agregaRegistro();">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" required="required" readonly="readonly" id="id-prod" name="id-prod" readonly="readonly" style="visibility:hidden; height:5px;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width="150">Proceso: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" required="required" readonly="readonly" id="pro" name="pro"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" required="required" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="100"/></td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>Tipo: </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" required="required" name="tipo" id="tipo" maxlength="100"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>URL: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" required="required" name="precio-uni" id="precio-uni"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Numero: </td>
                        <td><input type="number"  required="required" name="precio-dis" id="precio-dis"/></td>
                    </tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div id="mensaje"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-success" id="reg"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-warning"  id="edi"/>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

El php para ingresar los productos:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$database_connection=  database_connect();
$id = $_POST['id-prod'];
$proceso = $_POST['pro'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$precio_uni = $_POST['precio-uni'];
$precio_dis = $_POST['precio-dis'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
//VERIFICAMOS EL PROCESO

switch($proceso){
    case 'Registro':
        $database_connection->query("INSERT INTO productos (nomb_prod, tipo_prod, precio_unit, precio_dist, fecha_reg)VALUES('$nombre','$tipo','$precio_uni','$precio_dis', '$fecha')");
    break;

    case 'Edicion':
        $database_connection->query("UPDATE productos SET nomb_prod = '$nombre', tipo_prod = '$tipo', precio_unit = '$precio_uni', precio_dist = '$precio_dis' WHERE id_prod = '$id'");
    break;
}


//ACTUALIZAMOS LOS REGISTROS Y LOS OBTENEMOS

$registro = $database_connection->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id_prod ASC");

//CREAMOS NUESTRA VISTA Y LA DEVOLVEMOS AL AJAX

echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th width="0px">Nombre</th>
                            <th width="0px">Descripcion</th>
        <th width="50">Opciones</th>
            </tr>';
$registro = $database_connection-> query("SELECT * FROM productos")->fetchAll();
    foreach ($registro as $registro2){
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$registro2['nomb_prod'].'</td>
                <td><a href="https://'.$registro2['precio_unit'].'">'.$registro2['tipo_prod'].'</a></td>
                                <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></a></td>
                </tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

La pagina:

```
http://hzforo.byethost24.com/?i=1
```

Cualquiera puede entrar en la pagina y agregar algo. Pero el problema es si escribo algo en unicode en la tabla de mi base de datos si lo introduce en caracter unicode se vera de esta manera el campo `????????` hay alguna manera de solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buen dia. emm, el tema del juego de caracteres es un tanto complicado, todos tus archivos y tus datos deberían tener la misma codificación(juego de caracteres) para que puedan verse adecuadamente, intentaré darte algunos tips.

1. Tus archivos deberían estar guardados en una codificación que soporte caracteres mundiales, el standard actual es utf-8, tu editor de codigo debería guardar tus archivos en esa codificación, y todos los archivos que uses deberían concordar en dicha codificación, de lo contrario en php por ejemplo un file_get_contents podría no mostrar la ñ por ejemplo.PD: también influye que existan caaracteres antes del primer
2. El juego de caracteres de tu base de datos, tablas, celdas debería estar en la misma codificación, el standad es utf8_general_ci aunque ya existen otras codificaciónes más completas que también son utf8.
3. Aunque aun existen páginas maquetadas en html4, lo adecuado es utilizar las cabeceras de html5, esto lo pude notar en tu página, estás usando etiquetas html4 y html5 combinadas, para que te funcione correctamente utf8 en html tendrías que modificar lo siguiente al inicio de tu codigo:

   (Todo Tiene un espacio luego del primer <)
   < !DOCTYPE html> <-- esto es todo  -->

   <-- tu tienes: < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> -->

   < html lang="es"> <-- espefica el idioma de la web, esto es para los buscadores -->

   <-- tu tienes: < html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> lang en espeficia que el lenguaje será en inglés -->

   < meta charset="UTF-8"> <-- juego de caracteres que se usa en la página, es importante  las mayusculas y el guion -->

   <-- tu tienes: < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> y también < meta charset="utf-8"> esta etiqueta está de más por agregar la primer linea que ejemplifiqué, además no tiene mayusculas :P

Comment: no puse utf8 en phpmyadmin en el campo gracias por su ayuda me sirvio un montón!